# How to setup tcp server to cloud?

Tags: node.js

I'm setting up a new tcp server to cloud using node. But i can't access it through my local computer with internet. Or is it possible to run a TCP server on the cloud?

I'm trying to connect to the IP of address of the cloud. But seems that nothing happened. I hope you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: Who is the service provider (AWS, Google Cloud, etc.)?

Comment: @Janith Digital Ocean.